# How to set padding on text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to set padding on text widget. I have placed the padding widget and padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 200), but the Text still does not change position. Can anyone help me what widget I can use. I want the text to be on the top edge of the corner of the item box. I think the padding widget is the most suitable. Did I set it wrong. Please help.

```
Container(
                        color: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 200),
                                child: const Text(
                                  "Upcoming",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 20),
                              _upcomingAppointmentList.length > 0
                                  ? Center(
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: _upcomingAppointmentList
                                            .map((item) =>
                                                appointmentBoxWithShadow(
                                                    context,
                                                    item,
                                                    screenWidth,
                                                    widget.token))
                                            .toList()
                                            .cast<Widget>(),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : Text(_listLoadingInfo)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: Hello, I think you just need to change "right" to "left" ?

Comment: Thanks, dude. I wrong set. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with Container and set alignment to Alignment.centerRight